# AWS::CloudFormation::Init fails to create files from S3 Bucket although the retrieval via aws "s3 cp s3" is successful

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I was trying to retreive a file from S3 Bucket during initialization of EC2 instance.
There are no failures (Syntax). But there is something missing.
The initial_setup.sh file is not created in the root directory
There are so many articles all state the same (or at least as per my humble understanding as newbie)

```
Parameters:
 MyVPC: { Type: String, Default: vpc-000xxx }
 myNstdKeyName: { Type: String, Default: xxx-key-test }
 myNstdBucket: { Type: String, Default: myBucket }
 myNstdEC2HostSubnet: { Type: String, Default: subnet-0xxxxx }
 myNstdImageId: { Type: 'AWS::EC2::Image::Id', Default: 'ami-0xxxx' }

Resources:
#Allow incoming SSH and all types of outgoing traffic
 SSHSecGrp4Pub:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  Properties:
   GroupDescription: Security group to allow SSH connection in public subnet
   VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
   SecurityGroupIngress: [ { IpProtocol: tcp, FromPort: 22, ToPort: 22, CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0  } ]
   SecurityGroupEgress: [ { IpProtocol: -1, CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0, FromPort: 1, ToPort: 65535 } ]
#Assume Role  
 SAPEC2Role:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
   AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
   RoleName: EC2AWSAccess
   AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Statement: [ { Effect: Allow, Principal: { Service: ec2.amazonaws.com } , Action: [ 'sts:AssumeRole' ] }  ]
#Policy for the above role
 S3RolePolicy:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
  Properties:
   PolicyName: "S3DownloadPolicy"
   Roles: [ !Ref SAPEC2Role ]
   PolicyDocument:
    Statement:
     - Effect: Allow
       Action: [ 's3:GetObject' ]
       Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${myNstdBucket}/*"
#Profile for EC2 Instance       
 SAPEC2Profile:
  Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile 
  Properties: { InstanceProfileName: SAPEC2Profile,  Roles: [ !Ref SAPEC2Role ] }
#My EC2 Instance  
 EC2:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Metadata:
   AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication: 
    S3Access: 
     type: "S3"
     roleName: { Ref: "SAPEC2Role" }
     buckets: [ !Ref myNstdBucket ]
   AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
    config:
     files:
      /root/initial_setup.sh: {
       source: !Sub "https://${myNstdBucket}.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/initial_setup.sh", 
       mode: "000777", 
       owner: root, 
       group: root, 
       authentication: "S3Access" 
       }
     commands:
       myStarter:
         command: "/bin/bash  /root/initial_setup.sh"  
  Properties:
   SubnetId: !Ref myNstdEC2HostSubnet
   ImageId: !Ref myNstdImageId
   InstanceType: t2.micro
   KeyName: !Ref myNstdKeyName
   IamInstanceProfile: !Ref SAPEC2Profile
   SecurityGroupIds: [ !Ref SSHSecGrp4Pub ]
   UserData:
    Fn::Base64: !Sub |
     #!/bin/bash 
     echo "my test file" > /root/testfile.txt
```

After the instance is initialized and i try it out with aws cp s3://mybucket/initial_setup.sh
It works but i have to go over with dos2unix.

The alternative would be to put it in UserData. But this should also work with commands. (^)

Someone also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40707286/aws-cfn-init-not-creating-a-file?rq=1) had almost the same situation but it was mentioned that :

***"For any commands to work we need to provide a shell environment in Userdata without which it cannot create any files"***

And i added it too as a last line after the security group.

```
   UserData:
    Fn::Base64: !Sub |
     #!/bin/bash 
     echo "my test file" > /root/testfile.txt
```

So the /root/testfile.txt gets created with the specified text in it.

But the required file from the bucket did not show up.

Answer (score 0):

i had a misconception that just by stating Metadata Stuff, it will get executed as well. But now i'm half way through.
This was the missing part under the UserData

```
UserData:
 Fn::Base64:  !Sub |
  cd /tmp
  wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz
  gzip -df aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz
  tar -xvf aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar
  chmod -R 755 /tmp/aws-cfn-bootstrap-1.4
  pip install --upgrade pip
  pip install --upgrade setuptools
  pip install awscli --ignore-installed six &> /dev/null
  export PYTHONPATH=/tmp/aws-cfn-bootstrap-1.4
  /tmp/aws-cfn-bootstrap-1.4/bin/cfn-init -v  --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource EC2 --region ${AWS::Region}
```

It is actually the last line which makes the difference. The lines before it were used to setup the configuration as the image used is a non-aws image. So it does not bring the capability out of the box.